# Panel in Java Applet does not display

Tags: java, html, applet, awt

I have a Java Applet (`java.applet.Applet`) embedded into an HTML page.  There is a Control class, which `extends Applet` and a Panel (`java.awt.Panel`) the same shape and size of the Applet which displays everything on the screen.

When I run the project from the NetBeans IDE, everything displays as intended: the Applet opens and contains a Panel with my splash screen.

When I run the project from the HTML page on my website, I see a blank white page.  The images *do* load; in Google Chrome, I can right-click the page and click "Inspect Element", and the whole game displays and functions properly.  You can view the page at http://www.philipthegreat.com/control.html.

My thought: the Panel is displaying *behind* the Applet instead of *in front of* the Applet.

Here is the code in the Control and SplashScreen classes.

**Control**

```
public class Control extends Applet {

private Panel displayPanel;


 @Override
 public void init() {
    setFocusable(true);
 }

 @Override
 public void start() {
    displayPanel = new SplashScreen(this);
    add(displayPanel);
    displayPanel.requestFocus();
 }

 public void setDisplayPanel (Panel displayPanel) {
    remove(this.displayPanel);
    this.displayPanel = displayPanel;
    add(this.displayPanel);
    this.displayPanel.requestFocus();
 }

}
```

**SplashScreen**

```
public SplashScreen(Control control) {
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(800,600);
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    this.control = control;
    init();
}

public void init() {
    try {
                splashScreen = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/SplashScreen.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    addMouseListener((MouseListener) this);
}

public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(splashScreen, 0, 0, null);
}
```

As I am relatively new to Java, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) When you run it via html, do you get any error messages in the browser's Java console? 2) You look like you really want to use a CardLayout rather than manually swap components. 3) You're better off creating Swing JApplets not AWT Applets. 4) Many will say that you may be far better off using neither, that applet technology is passe, and that most folks are using HTML5/CSS/JS.

Comment: I'll look into CardLayout with a Swing JApplet.  The rest of my project (a basic side-scrolling shooter) depends heavily on java.awt.  I've been using Applet instead of JApplet because I've read I should not mix Swing and AWT components.  Is it a good idea in this case?

Comment: I did not know I could view the Java Console error messages in the browser.  There are not any error messages.  For anyone reading after this: Here's how you view the console. http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: What about the html code? If this works perfectly fine when started over netbeans, then this could also be an "error" in html than in the applet. You may look at the html code generated from netbeans by compiling the source and have a look at the generated html file in the dist folder. If this html shows your Applet perfectly well in Chrome, this isn't an applet problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as Control.java instead of your Control.java

```
//<applet code="Control.java" height=200 width=500></applet>
public class Control extends JApplet {
    private Panel displayPanel;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        displayPanel = new SplashScreen(this);
        add(displayPanel);
        displayPanel.requestFocus();
    }

    public void setDisplayPanel(Panel displayPanel) {
        remove(this.displayPanel);
        this.displayPanel = displayPanel;
        add(this.displayPanel);
        this.displayPanel.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to a JApplet did not change the results. I have the JApplet version posted at http://www.philipthegreat.com/control_1.html

Comment: Have you tried adding the comment line in your code? written at top of the code

Comment: Yeah http://www.philipthegreat.com/control_1.html is working fine in my system, which browser you are using, try google chrome, or check your browser supports java runtime or not, if not install the plugins to support java

Comment: Thank you for 1. confirming that the Applet displays properly for you, and 2. the tip about the commented-out line at the top.  I don't understand (yet) why that made a difference, but it did.

Comment: I have seen a lot of useless comments by  Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I would not use his knowledge. Just a personal suggestion since I have been on stackoverflow.